# Angular gemStore doesn't output anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently trying out angularJS to see how it works. 
I followed a tutorial on egghead.io which is quite good.

Came up with this fiddle but it annoys me that I cant find the issue/error.
Nothing shows/outputs

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('gemStore', []);

    app.controller('StoreController', function() { 
      this.products = gems;
    });


    var gems = [
        {
            name: "Soap",
            price: 25,
            quantity: 10,
            canPurchase: false
        }, 
        {
            name: "Bag",
            price: 100,
            quantity: 15,
            canPurchase: false
        }
    ];

});
```

**index**

```
<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
<div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
    <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
    <h2>${{product.price}}</h2>
    <button ng-show="product.canPurchase">Add to cart</button>
</div>
```

This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/618/ (UPDATED)
Hope you could point me in the right direction.

In advance, thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle outputs `ReferenceError: angular is not defined` in the console ;-)

Comment: Ok - What is the next step. How do I define it in jsfiddle?

Comment: There is a button, as I mention in my answer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/615/ updated your fiddle check it. you didn't include angular js library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include angular in your page. Simply add:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

to your HTML page. Note that jsfiddle has a button on the top left under "Frameworks & Extensions" that allows you to quick-add libraries such as angular.

You also forgot to call your IIFE:

```
(function() {
    //Your JS...
})(); //<--- you forgot the ()
```

[I forked your fiddle and fixed those issues](https://jsfiddle.net/8pb5eb52/), it works just fine.

Comment: Woops. Sorry LionC. It's the wrong fiddle. Use this https://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/618/

Comment: I get this error in my console 
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @Rorabih You forgot to call the big function you wrapped your code in it. So just add a `()` to the end of your JS before the last `;`

Comment: @LionC
yes just saw he forgot to call it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call the self calling function:
JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Vwsej/620/

This is how self calling structure is:

```
(function(){
    // your js code to execute
})();//forgot to call
```